# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range when trying to access GameObject array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope

So I'm trying to access an element from GameObject array initialized with FindGameObjectsWithTag but I get the following error

> "IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.",

when I print the length of the array I get 3, as it should be. How do I fix it?

```
public class selectObject : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject[] objects;
    void Start () {
        GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("isari");  
        Debug.Log (objects.Length);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("Mouse is down");

            RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();
            bool hit = Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo);
        if (hit) 
        {
            Vector3 position = hitInfo.transform.gameObject.transform.position;
            Quaternion rotation = hitInfo.transform.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            Debug.Log("Hit " + hitInfo.transform.gameObject.name);
            Object.Instantiate (objects[0], position,rotation);

            Object.Destroy (hitInfo.transform.gameObject);

            if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "Construction")
            {
                Debug.Log ("It's working!");
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("nopz");
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log("No hit");
        }
        Debug.Log("Mouse is down");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You declare a local `objects[]` variable in the `Start` function hiding the field `objects`. just remove the declaration of `objects` array from `start` function

You can try this.

```
public GameObject[] objects;
void Start () {
    objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("isari");  
    Debug.Log (objects.Length);
}
```